# Mensagem com uma pergunta de confirmação antes de concluir o evento click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gerenciamento de tarefas no qual é realizado alterações em campos no banco de dados dependendo de certos botões que clicamos (Via Ajax e PHP).

Eu gostaria de que, ao clicarmos em um botão, seja aberto um alert, um modal ou algo assim com uma pergunta do tipo: "Deseja mesmo realizar essa alteração ?". Se fosse clicado no botão "SIM", então seria concluído aquela ação. Se fosse clicado no botão "NÃO", então nada seria feito e o evento não seria chamado.

**Segue abaixo o meu código.**

```js
/* Função que cria as linhas da tabela com os botões dinamicamente */

function inserirFormulario(dados) {
  $.ajax({
    //dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: dados.serialize(),
    url: "../banco/banco-get/pagina-minhas-tarefas/interface-resultado-pesquisa.php",
    cache: false,


  }).done(function(data) {

    var atividades = "";

    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor) {

      //FUNÇÃO PARA FORMATAR AS DATAS QUE VEM DO PHP
      function dataAtualFormatada(parametro) {
        if (parametro == null) {
          parametro = "";
          return parametro;
        } else {
          var data = new Date(parametro),
            dia = data.getDate().toString(),
            diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0' + dia : dia,
            mes = (data.getMonth() + 1).toString(), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
            mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0' + mes : mes,
            anoF = data.getFullYear();
          return diaF + "/" + mesF + "/" + anoF;
        }
      }


      var vencimento = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_VENCIMENTO);
      var inicio = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_INICIO);
      var fim = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_FIM);


      //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 

      atividades += '<tr class="' + valor.codigo + '" name="' + valor.STATUS + '">';
      //atividades += '<td>' + valor.codigo + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + valor.COD + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.EMPRESAS + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + valor.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + valor.TIPO_ATIVIDADE + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td>' + vencimento + '</td>';
      //atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + inicio + '</td>';
      //atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody">' + fim + '</td>';


      if (valor.STATUS == "INICIADO") {
        atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-iniciado" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO") {
        atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-concluido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO") {
        atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-concluido-vencido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "VENCIDO") {
        atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-vencido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "PENDENTE") {
        atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby css-pendente" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "INICIADO_VENCIDO") {
        atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade colocarstandby css-iniciado-vencido" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      }

      //botão stand_by do status
      else if (valor.STATUS == "STAND_BY") {
        atividades += '<td><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' css-stand-by" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      }

      //botão reabrir atividade coluna
      atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody"><button type="button" class="btn css-reabrir reabrir-atividade-coluna" name="' + valor.STATUS + '" value="' + valor.codigo + '"><img src="../_imagens/reabrir.png"></button></td>';

      //botão stand by da coluna
      atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary stand-by-coluna" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inserir-stand-by" id="' + valor.codigo + '"  value="' + valor.COD + '"><img src="../_imagens/stand_by.png"></button></td>';

      //botão inserir detalhes
      atividades += '<td class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody"><button type="button" class="btn css-detalhes botao-detalhes" <a class="" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-observacoes"><img src="../_imagens/historicotarefa.png"></a></button></td>';
      //botão inserir detalhes
      //atividades += '<td><a  class="btn btn-md btn-primary css-detalhes " href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-observacoes"><img src="_imagens/historicotarefa.png"></a></button></td>';


      atividades += '</tr>';


    });

    $('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);


  }).fail(function() {


  }).always(function() {


  });
}


//Código que realiza o evento quando clicamos no botão do modal

$(document).on("click", ".transformar-atividade-para-stand-by", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


  if (!$(this).closest("tr").find(".STAND_BY").length) //Não vai executar a ação se número de classes STAND_BY na linha for maior que ZERO
  {

    var tipo_ativ = 'STAND_BY'; /*$(this).attr('class')*/
    //andrews//////////////////////////////
    $(this).css('background-color', '#424242');
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
    $(this).css('color', 'white');
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
    $(this).css('border-radius', '5px');
    //andrews//////////////////////////////
    var codigo_emp = $(this).attr('id');
    var cod_emp = $(this).val();
    var estado_anterior_do_campo = $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.colocarstandby").html();

    $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.colocarstandby").html("STAND_BY");
    $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.colocarstandby").css('background-color', 'black');



    //VERIFICANDO O STATUS DO CAMPO QUE RECEBERÁ O NOVO STATUS (STAND_BY)

    if (estado_anterior_do_campo == "PENDENTE") {
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('css-pendente');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('css-stand-by');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('STAND_BY');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('PENDENTE');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('colocarstandby');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('reabriratividade');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabrir-atividade-coluna").attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'STAND_BY');

    } else if (estado_anterior_do_campo == "INICIADO") {
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('css-iniciado');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('css-stand-by');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('STAND_BY');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('INICIADO');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('colocarstandby');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('reabriratividade');


      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabrir-atividade-coluna").attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
    } else if (estado_anterior_do_campo == "CONCLUIDO") {
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('css-concluido');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('css-stand-by');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('STAND_BY');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('CONCLUIDO');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('colocarstandby');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('reabriratividade');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabrir-atividade-coluna").attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
    } else if (estado_anterior_do_campo == "VENCIDO") {
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('css-vencido');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('css-stand-by');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('STAND_BY');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('VENCIDO');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('colocarstandby');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('reabriratividade');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabrir-atividade-coluna").attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
    } else if (estado_anterior_do_campo == "INICIADO_VENCIDO") {
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('css-iniciado-vencido');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('css-stand-by');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('STAND_BY');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('INICIADO_VENCIDO');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('colocarstandby');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('reabriratividade');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabrir-atividade-coluna").attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
    } else if (estado_anterior_do_campo == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO") {
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('css-concluido-vencido');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('css-stand-by');

      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('STAND_BY');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('colocarstandby');
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('reabriratividade');


      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " button.reabrir-atividade-coluna").attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'STAND_BY');
    }

    //CHAMANDO FUNÇÃO QUE UTILIZA O AJAX PARA ALTERAR O STATUS PARA STAND_BY NO BANCO DE DADOS

    var alterarstandby = transformarStandBy(tipo_ativ, codigo_emp, cod_emp);

    tipo_ativ = "";
  }

});
```

```html
<!-- Modal que é aberto quando clicamos no botão -->

<div class="modal fade" id="inserir-stand-by" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Você realmente deseja passar essa atividade para Stand By ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary transformar-atividade-para-stand-by" id="transformar-em-stand-dy">Sim</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Não</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Não vou postar o código aqui porque ele é muito extenso. Gostaria apenas de uma luz de como fazer algo assim. De preferência utilizando jQuery. Vou deixar abaixo um pequeno exemplo do click em um dos botões do modal (Botão ".transformar-atividade-para-stand-by").. Sendo que o código jQuery proveniente desse evento não está acontecendo.

**Segue abaixo uma imagem do sistema.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, quando clicamos no botão da coluna "STAND BY", Ele muda o status da coluna "STATUS" para o status STAND_BY. Essa mudança também ocorre no banco de dados.

Se alguém puder me ajudar...

Comment: Essa solução pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Thiago.

Você pode utilizar uma lib chamada [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com), vale lembrar que o bootbox trabalha ao lado do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Exemplo de como ficaria o código:

```js
bootbox.confirm({
    message: "Deseja mesmo realizar essa alteração?",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Sim',
            className: 'btn-success'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'Não',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
        if(result) {
            //CÓDIGO QUE EFETUA AS ALTERAÇÕES....
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: fiz e não funcionou. Coloquei essa código seu, dentro do meu evento click. Então coloquei o código que efetua as alterações no local que você mencionou. Porém, o alert (da lib) até é chamado, porém não executa as alterações do meu código.

Comment: Substitua todos os $(this) por $(".STAND_BY")

Comment: Vou alterar meu código pra vc ver como ficou

Comment: O botão é o ".stand-by-coluna".

Comment: Ahhh legal, você alterou e deu certo?

Comment: Ele só realiza a alteração no primeiro botão da lista. Não está fazendo da forma correta.

Comment: Vou voltar o código antigo pra ve se alguém tem outra solução. Dessa forma está meio complexo e achei que ficou muito pesado. Mas agradeço, @André Luis.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, de uma olhadinha no link: [https://sweetalert2.github.io](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)/
É um tipo personalizado para as caixas de POP-UP do js, ele já vem todo personalizado com vários tipos de mensagens.